# Active Standby in MicroService using Spring Boot

Tags: microservices, ribbon

I am in a situation where I have a microservice environment but for one service I want that it should not be load balanced rather work in a active standby(one at a time serves the request). When one service instance goes down then only the requests should be routed to the other instance even if the first one comes up the 2nd instance should be the one servicing the requests.

I am looking for the options like - overriding ribbon's IRule or doing this in a @PreFilter which is there on each of these services.

Let me know if anyone has any implementation for the above case.

Comment: If you can't load balance, it implies that your service is stateful, which would lead to problems when failing over to the active standby.